# Ignore string if it starts with another word regex perl

Tags: regex, xml, perl

I am reading an XML file in which I am replacing certain words. I don't want to replace words that come in XML elements or attributes. I'm using negative look behind and look ahead and I'm 90% there. However, if a value comes in an attribute that contains the string which I want to replace then it is getting replaced. I don't want that.

My regex:

```
-$fi=~s/(?<!<|\/)(?<!value=")\bis\b(?!=)/iss/g
```

This regex does not match elements attributes and value attributes. But if there is a text like `value="hello there"` and I am replacing `there` with some word then it is getting replaced. I want a regex that will search if the word `there` is not preceded at the start of `value="`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454  You'd be much better off using an XML parser, and then fiddling with the data

Comment: Yes it's a project requirement and this text iss getting replaced in perl so i want a negative lookbehind to check if text has value=" before and if yes then skip it.

Comment: could you provide a input example and it's expected matches?

Comment: Ex:- like if the xml is like <p1 value="Hello there">There</p1> So is should replace on standalone value There and not the text which is present in attribute value.

Comment: You are setting yourself an impossibly hard task if you are both trying to parse XML and exclude quoted strings using regex. I would never even bother attempting such an excruciating task when the alternative of just using an XML parser is so much simpler. It is possible to use regex for a small, well-known set of XML, but you would risk breaking your data.